# Ошибка Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB'

Tags: sql

```
Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of insufficient disk space in 
filegroup 'DEFAULT'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding 
additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.
```

Такую ошибку выдает запуск .exe файла. Его задача собрать строчки с SQL базы данных из таблиц локализации в файлы для дальнейшего использования в проекте. Сама база настроена на автоматическое увеличение в 100MB без ограничения на максимальный размер. На текущий момент размер БД составляет 95GB, свободного места на диске, куда проложен путь для генерации файлов с локализацией более чем хватает - 200+GB. Какие ещё есть способы решения данной проблемы?

Также были проверены настройки tempDB, там также настройки проставлены с увеличением на 10% текущей памяти, и убран лимит.

UPD2: предоставлю содержимое cfg файла, который используется для сборки:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
       <add key="SQLConnectString" value="Pooling=true; PersistSecurityInfo=False;
    Server=***;Connect Timeout=600;
    user=admin;password=pass;       
    Database=LocalizationDB;Max Pool Size=100;
    Min Pool Size=1;Packet Size=4096" />
        <add key="LocalGeodataPath" value="E:/Projects/lng/" />
   <add key="AvailableLanguages" value="ru;en;de;es;pl;fr;lt;pt;tr;ro;sr;he;jp"/>
   <add key="OnlyFileCreate" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Результатом выполнения команды

```
select SUM(size * 8.0 / 1024) as [Total Size, Mb] from sys.master_files
```

Стал результат: 248400.187500

Можно ли на основе этого сделать вывод, что недостаточно места на диске куда выгружаются данные с tempdb, и для решения проблемы необходима установка дополнительной памяти?

Comment: Какая версия сервера?

Comment: SQL 2012 Enterprise Edition

Comment: посмотрите что вернёт: select SUM(size * 8.0 / 1024) as [Total Size, Mb] from sys.master_files

Comment: Дополнил стартовый пост.

Comment: и сколько всего места на вашем диске при этом?

Comment: 248ГБ, свободных 200.

Я так понимаю, проблема в том что раньше данная программа собиралась на другой машине, на которой было больше свободного места.

Comment: Вы точно проверяете место на диске с tempdb, а не на диске с основной базой?

Comment: Основная база и tempdb находятся на одном диске.